# What is the most common method used to cool hydrogen below its boiling point?

Tags: hydrogen, gas, energy-storage

I would like to know what methods companies/organizations/scientists use to cool gaseous hydrogen below its boiling point of ~250 degrees Celsius. I am a new student to thermochemistry and am not exceedingly well-versed in this area.

Thank you in advance!